# How to break out of an async series inside an async.each loop - node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I need to skip functions or breakout of a an async.series, and was wondering how I should go about it. I have an array of items that I need to iterate through. I put that list in a async.each function. Each item in the array then goes through a list of functions needed before moving on, in a series (as info from one is needed in the next). But in some cases, I only need to go through the first function, then if a condition isn't met (example, it is a category we don't use), then callback to the async.each loop for the next item. Here is an example of my code:

```
exports.process_items = function(req, res, next){
var user = res.locals.user;
var system = res.locals.system;
var likes = JSON.parse(res.locals.likes);
var thecat;

 //process each item
 async.each(items, function(item, callback){
   //with each item, run a series of functions on it...
   thecat = item.category;

   async.series([
    //Get the category based on the ID from the DB...
    function(callback) {
        //do stuff
        callback(); 
    },

    //before running other functions, is it an approved category?
    //if it is not an approved category, SKIP THE OTHER FUNCTIONS IN THE LIST (but how?)
    function(callback) {
         //do stuff
         callback();
    },

     //some other functionality run on that item, 
    function(callback){
        //do stuff
        callback():
    }


  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log("done with series of functions, next item in the list please");
});

//for each like callback...
callback();

}, function(err){
     //no errors
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put exit shortcuts at the top of the dependent functions. For example:

```
async.series([
    //Get the category based on the ID from the DB...
    function(callback) {
        //do stuff
        callback(); 
    },

    //before running other functions, is it an approved category?
    //if it is not an approved category, SKIP THE OTHER FUNCTIONS IN THE LIST (but how?)
    function(callback, results) {
         if (results[0] is not an approved category) return callback();
         //do stuff
         callback();
    },
```

Comment: But that will just exit that function right? Or will asking it to return the callback end the series? I'm wanting to end the series without running all of the other functions in the series, and to go back to the async.each again.

Comment: It doesn't end the series, but it stops any work from happening and sends control back to async.each. You need one of those at the beginning of any function you don't want to run if the result is not approved. I also just noticed that you need a call to callback right after the console.log line. It's easy to get tripped up with all the different callback functions floating around.